# Is there a way to select a child element inside another child element in Watin

Tags: watin

I am trying to select a link/button inside of a form, that is in a div. the way it was made is that there are two links/buttons of the same id, name etc. however they are in different forms, so the code i wanted to use is:

_myTest.Form(Find.ById("PermissionsForm")).Child(Find.ByClass("saveBtn")).Child(Find.ByText("SAVE"));

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
var button = _myTest.Form("PermissionsForm").Button(Find.ByClass("saveBtn"));
```

This will lookup the button having the class 'saveBtn' inside the form 'permissionsform' in your browser instance _myTest.

Have a look at this [page](http://watin.org/documentation/element-class-mapping-table/) to decide if you need to have .Button(..) or .Link(...) based on the html tag that is used in your html.

Answer (score 0):

How about building a regex for the element?

Regex could something like this
Regex elementRe = new Regex("id=LnkOk href="http://stackoverflow.com");

Then you can use your code to Click this link. The Click method can be extended to accept Regex if it is not already doing that.

Let me know how this goes or if you need more info.
Cheers,
DM